# multiple tabs scenario in playwright

Tags: playwright

What is the correct way to work on a new browser Tab using playwright.
Here is my scenario
After I navigate to a page 'a' I click on link 'x' which opens a new browser tab i.e. a new page 'b'. (Both pages has web tables on it.)
Now I want to work on page 'b' web table.
But it appears that I end up working on page 'a' web table instead

```
        const [tabs] = await Promise.all([
        this.page.context().waitForEvent('page'),
        this.page.click(`x`)
    ])
    await tabs.waitForLoadState('networkidle');
    expect(await tabs.title()).toEqual('some title');
    // get the number of open tabs
    const openTabs = await tabs.context().pages()
    await openTabs[1].bringToFront()
```

At this point I want to work on page 'b',
Appreciate any help

Comment: unless I start forming my locator using `openTabs[1]` I cannot work on `openTabs[1]` i.e. page 'b' elements. This works `await openTabs[1].locator('tbody tr.clickable')` and this `await locator('tbody tr.clickable')` does not work when I am already on `openTabs[1]`

Answer (score 3):

Handling newly opened tabs in Playwright is far from intuitive if you're not used to it. A summary of how they work:

If you click a link in your test with `target="_blank"`, which opens a new tab, the `page` object you're working with *still refers to the original page/tab you opened the link on.*

To get ahold of the new page, you have to:

```js
const [newPage] = await Promise.all([
    context.waitForEvent('page'), // get `context` by destructuring with `page` in the test params; 'page' is a built-in event, and **you must wait for this like this,**, or `newPage` will just be the response object, rather than an actual Playwright page object.
    page.locator('text=Click me').click() // note that, like all waiting in Playwright, this is somewhat unintuitive. This is the action which is *causing the navigation*; you have to set up the wait *before* it happens, hence the use of Promise.all().
])

 await newPage.waitForLoadState(); // wait for the new tab to fully load
 // now, use `newPage` to access the newly opened tab, rather than `page`, which will still refer to the original page/tab.
 await expect(newPage).toHaveURL('http://www.someURL.com');
 await newPage.locator('text=someText');
```