# How to implement Page Object Models using context browser in Playwright in javascript?

Tags: javascript, pom.xml, playwright, fixtures

I'm starting with Playwrgiht in Javascript.

I'm using POM+Fixture+ test

Actually:

POM 1:

```
import { URLS, CREDENCIALES } from '../data/Constantes';

exports.Login = class Login {
/\*\*
\*

* @param {import ('@playwright/test').Page} page
  \*/
  constructor(page) {
  this.page = page;
  this.inicioHUserInput = "#name";
  this.inicioHPassInput = "#password";
  this.ingresarBtn = 'button:has-text("Ingresar")';
  };

async gotoURL() {
await this.page.goto(URLS.URL);
};

async ingreso() {
await this.page.locator(this.inicioHUserInput).fill(CREDENCIALES.USER);
await this.page.locator(this.inicioHPassInput).fill(CREDENCIALES.PASS);
await this.page.locator(this.ingresarBtn).click();
};
};
```

POM 2:

```
exports.S = class S {
/\*\*
\*

* @param {import ('@playwright/test').Page} page
  \*/

    constructor(page) {
        this.page = page;
         //Buttons
        this.inicioSBtn = '#apps > div:nth-child(3) > div.row > div:nth-child(3) > a > p';        
    };
    
    async ingresoS() {
        await this.page.locator(this.inicioSBtn).click();
    };

};
```

POM 3:

```
exports.S2 = class S2 {
/\*\*
\*

* @param {import ('@playwright/test').Page} page
  \*/

    constructor(page) {
        this.page = page;
        this.sudocuGestionBtn = '#btn_login_gestion';    
      
    };
    async ingresoGestion() {
        const newPage = await this.page.waitForEvent('popup');
        await newPage.locator(this.sudocuGestionBtn).click();
       // await newPage.waitForLoadState('domcontentloaded');                    
    };

};
```

FIXTURE :

```
const base = require('@playwright/test');
import { Locator, Page, test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
import { URLS, CREDENCIALES } from '../data/Constantes';
const { Login } = require("../pages/loginH");
const { S } = require("../pages/s");
const { S2 } = require("../pages/s2");

exports.test = base.test.extend({
webApp: async ({ page }, use) =\> {
const login = new Login(page);
const page1 = new S(page);
const su2 = new S2(page);

    await login.gotoURL();
    await login.ingreso();
    
    await page1.ingresoS();
    await su2.ingresoGestion();
    await use(page); 

},
});
exports.expect = base.expect;
```

TEST:

```
const { test, expect } = require("../tests/fixtureGestion");
import { S } from "../pages/s";
import { Login } from "../pages/loginH";
import { webApp } from "../tests/fixtureGestion";

const { fakerES: faker } = require('@faker-js/faker');
//import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker/locale/es';

test("Capturar pantalla de página de gestión", async ({ webApp, page }) =\> {

      await page.screenshot({ path: "pagina_de_gestion.png" });

});
```

But I don't know implement context in POM 2. The screenshot is in the page incorrect.
Is possible use context in POM and after using Fixture?

Thanks!

I see and try:

[multiple tabs scenario in playwright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72092929/multiple-tabs-scenario-in-playwright)

[How to handle new tabs with the page object model with Playwright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74054137/how-to-handle-new-tabs-with-the-page-object-model-with-playwright/77487606#77487606)